# Question about wording(sql)

Tags: ms-access

I just need help understanding what the following questions are asking for.

> 1. List all details about packages. Sort the output by descending package
>      cost within package type.

What I don't get is "within package type" I know this much: SELECT * FROM PACKAGE, ORDER PACKCOST DESC;

But I don't get the within??

> 1. List the average package cost for packages of each type. Then list only
>      averages for types containing more
>      than one package.

So for this one I guess I should do the average for each type, then the average for each type that has > 1 packages???

Sorry I don't have the tables.

Thanks.

Table fields:

PACKID  PACKNAME    PACKVER PACKTYPE    PACKCOST

Answer (score 0):

The first question wants you to limit the sorting so that it's grouped by package types. So let's say the package types are Box and Letter. First you would list all the Letter packages, by descending cost. Then you would list all the Box packages by descending cost. Your query right now would mix the Box and Letter packages together and the question doesn't want you to do that.

You seem to understand the other question correctly.

Comment: I have no idea how to do that in SQL

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, I would answer

```
select * from package order by packtype, packcost desc
```

This will first order the packages by type, and then *within each group* order them by cost.

Comment: For the second question: select packtype, avg(packcost) from packages group by packtype

Comment: For the second part of the second question: select packtype, avg(packcost) from packages group by packtype having count(1) > 1

Comment: select packtype, avg(packcost) from packages group by packtype having count(1) > 1

Wait doesn't that only satisfy the second condition?